# What kind of chili peppers are these?

Tags: chili-peppers

Having a long weekend, we have some new recipes we want to try. I found this recipe for  [Fried Green Chili Stuffed With Pork Stuffing](http://www.topchinesecuisine.com/2013/09/fried-green-chili-stuffed-with-pork-stuffing/) .

[image]

Unfortunately, the recipe doesn't say what type of chilies these are. They appear to be longer but more slender than a jalapeño, and just a little lighter in color. Per the recipe, each chili would hold roughly 62g of the stuffing.

I'm sure that I have seen these but can't remember what kind they are. I've been looking online, as well, but haven't found any that really look like they are these chilies.

We're going on the hunt. If anyone can tell me the name of this chili pepper it would be most appreciated.

Comment: There is a chart about halfway down this page: http://www.mommiecooks.com/2010/08/17/chile-peppers/  I'm not sure it helps.  My guess: Poblano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell with the sauce, but they look like they could be Korean chilis. I'm not sure if they have a more specific name, as I have only seen them sold as "Korean chili". They are fairly similar in flavor to North American green chilis, but maybe a bit hotter. They are usually a bit longer, and quite a bit more slender than something like an Anaheim chili.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! These definitely could be an option and if we're lucky we may be able to find them when we visit the international market later today.

Answer (score 5):

Those are "standard" green chilies. They might be Anaheim, California, New Mexico or Hatch. It's hard to tell from the picture, but the varieties are interchangeable. Just know that the New Mexico or Hatch varieties are hotter.

It may be a Chinese recipe, but I'm guessing that the chili is New World.

Comment: I looked up the varieties you listed and you are correct that they are interchangeable. However, the chilies we can get locally, such as Anaheim, are grown much larger than these. (They are large enough that they look like a lighter colored Poblano.) They would be much larger than what I would want to use in this recipe. Also, I'm not sure the ones in the recipe are 'New World'. I've looked through many recipes on the site and they do seem to be quite authentic.

Comment: @CindyAskew The fact (or not) that the chilies are of the New World wouldn't make the recipes less authentically Chinese. Chili peppers weren't introduced to Asia until the 15th or 16th centuries. If it's a chili, we (New World) grew it first. Those particular chilies look to me like Anaheim, California, New Mexico or Hatch.

Comment: They're definitely not Anaheim, based on the texture. I suspect that might rule out the others too, but I've only seen hatch roasted, and the others dried, I think.

Answer (score -2):

More than likely Shishito Pepper

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained why it's more than likely shishito.